# DIV randomly cutting off in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm having trouble with a background div cutting off randomly in Internet explorer...

Here is how it should look like, taken from a webkit/chromium browser..
[image: How it should look (A Webkit/Chromium Browser)]

Here is how Internet Explorer thinks it should look like...
[image: What the website looks like at the moment in a Internet Explorer Browser]

The web page can be found at http://beta.surrealholidays.com.
any feedback on how to fix this would be appreciated.

HTML Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link href="/css/alt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="robots" content="all">
<meta name="author" content="surrealholidays.com">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content ="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.surrealholidays.com/images/logo.ico">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="/js/flash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<title>Welcome to Surreal Holidays</title>
</head>
<body class="oneColFixCtr">
<div id="bannerph">
<div id="bannerint">
  <div id="logoph" align="left">
    <p><img src="/images/logos/newlogo.png" width="204" height="99" alt="Site Logo"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="callus" align="right">
    <p><br>
      Call Us:</p>
    <h1>0845 003 5043</h1></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page">
<div id="links">
<a href="/">Homepage</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="/destinations">Luxury Destinations</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="/tours">Private Tours</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="/terms/">Terms & Conditions</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="/enquire">Enquire</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="/news">News</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></div>
<div id="ct">



<div id="navig">
  <div class="c2 c1" id="navi_direc">
    <div align="left">Homepage &gt;</div>
  </div>
  <div id="navi_newsl"> <a href="/newsletter/index.html">Subscribe</a> to our Latest Offers</div>
</div>
<div id="img">
  <p><img src="/images/mainstory.jpg" width="995" height="400">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="hp_welcome">
<h2 align="left">Private Luxury Escorted Tours in Thailand </h2>
<p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left" class="c2"><strong>At Surreal Holidays, you can really feel the passion for Thailand. From the first moment you contact our experienced team, you will be amazed by the in-depth local knowledge and deep love of the country and its people that you encounter. Not surprising! Some of us were born and raised in Thailand before moving to the UK. You will find we have a unique ability to understand how travellers from the UK can experience the best Thailand has to offer. No ordinary travel company, Surreal Holidays can tailor a holiday especially for you. Along the way, your experience will be enhanced by our high levels of customer service and thoughtful personal touches.</strong></p>
<p class="c2">&nbsp;</p>
<h2 align="left" class="c3"><strong>Bespoke Holidays to Thailand</strong></h2>
<p align="left" class="c2"></p>
<p align="left" class="c2"><strong>Our founder's inspiration: "..like you, when I travel, I use all my senses to enhance the experience. This often leads to a "surreal" feeling, as though the holiday is a dream like state where the strange and bizarre juxtaposition with the calm and beautiful. Nowhere epitomises this more than Thailand, my homeland. Whether you are looking for an inspirational island hopping itinerary or romantic wedding and honeymoon locations, soft adventure activities or cultural experiences, you need look no further. Thailand offers much more than just a place to relax on a beach. You can discover unique flora and fauna, stunning marine parks, and breathtaking scenery at every turn. Indeed, there really is something for everyone in our Amazing Thailand."... Runci Weeden</strong></p>
<p align="left" class="c2">&nbsp;</p>
<h2 align="left" class="c3"><strong>Unique Holidays to Thailand</strong></h2>
<p align="left" class="c2"></p>
<p align="left" class="c2"><strong>To find out more information on our Escorted Tour Holidays, including Nature Tours, Cultural Tours or Adventure Tours to Thailand, call 0845 003 5043 and speak to our friendly team.</strong></p>
<p align="left" class="c2">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="col2">
<div id="hp_ftcol2off">
<h3 align="center"><strong>Our Latest Offers</strong></h3>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
<h3>Offers Coming Soon!</h3>
</p>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<h3 align="center">Layana Resort and Spa<br>
  From £89 pppn
</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="hp_ftcol2foll">
  <h3>Follow Us</h3>
  <p align="center" class="c2"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/SurrealHolidays"><img src="/images/social_icons/facebook.png" alt="Find us on Facebook" width="64" height="64" border="0"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/surrealholidays"><img src="/images/social_icons/twitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" width="64" height="64" border="0"></a><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/115488031855843811543/posts"><img src="/images/social_icons/google.png" alt="Find us on Google Plus" width="64" height="64" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/surrealholidays"><img src="/images/social_icons/youtube.png" alt="Watch us on Youtube" width="64" height="64" border="0"></a><a href="http://vimeo.com/surrealholidays"><img src="/images/social_icons/vimeo.png" alt="Watch us on Vimeo" width="64" height="64" border="0"></a><br>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="hp_ftcol2news">
<h3><strong>Latest News</strong></h3>
<h3>20 March 2012</h3>
  <h3><u><strong>Welcome To Our New Website!</strong></u>
    <br>
    We have now launched our brand new website, for an improved compatability for Tablet Devices, as well as a much faster loading speed for a enhanced browsing experience. For more information about this update, <br>
    <u>Click Here</u>.</h3>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center" class="c2"><br>
  <br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div id="f_tr">
<br>
Tel: 0845 003 5043 (Local Rates from a BT Landline) , 01628 685 550<br>
<strong>&copy; Surreal Holidays Ltd. 2009-2012 All Rights Reserved.</strong><br>
<div id="f_php">
  <div id="f_ph1"><img src="/images/logos/logo-amazing.png" width="145" height="45" alt="Thailand"></div>
<div id="f_ph2">
  <p>Surreal Holidays is the Trading Name of Surreal Holidays Ltd. Company Number: 06690344<br>
    <a href="/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a> | <a href="/privacypolicy">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/copyright">Copyright</a></p>
</div>
<div id="f_ph3">
<img src="/images/logos/logo-atol.png" width="45" height="45" alt="A"><img src="/images/logos/logo-atta.png" width="45" height="45" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- Closing Tags For #Footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
a:link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #fff;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#page {
    width:995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;

}

#ct {
    background-image:url(/images/bg.png);
    overflow:visible;
}

#bannerph {
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url(/images/banner.png)    
}
#bannerint {
    width: 995px;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
#logoph {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

#callus {
    width: 500px;
    float: right;

}
#links {
    background-image: url(/images/logos/li.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    }

#linkblock{
    padding: 10px;
}

#navig {
    height: 30px;
    width: 995px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#navi_direc{
    float:left;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#navi_direc a {
    color: #000
}

#navi_newsl{
    float: right;
    width: 449px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#content {
    height: auto;
    background-image: url(/images/mainbggrad.jpg)
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #7d6543;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#content h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#content h4 {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #8A5D3C;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#content h5 {
margin: 0px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: normal;
color: #8A5D3C;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
#col2 {
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#content p {
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
}
#hp_welcome{
    width: 550px;
    float:left;
    padding: 10 px;
    color: #7d6543;
}
#hp_ftcol2off {
    width:380px;
    float:right;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    background-image: url(/images/logos/news.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#hp_ftcol2news {
    width:380px;
    float:right;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-image: url(/images/logos/news.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#hp_ftcol2foll {
    width:380px;
    float:right;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-image: url(/images/logos/news.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#hp_ftcol2off table tr td {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#container_hp{
    width: 995px;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
#f_tr{
    height:auto;
}
#f_php{
    width: 995px;
    height: 60px;
}
#f_ph1{
    width:325px;
    float:left;
}
#f_ph2{
    width:340px;
    float:left;
    }
#f_ph3{
    width:325px;
    float:left;
}
#footer {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(/images/logos/ftr.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 150px;
    padding-bottom: -5px;
}

#callus {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#navi_newsl a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navi_newsl a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#navi_newsl a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000;
}
#navi_newsl a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.oneColFixCtr #bannerint #callus h1 {
    color: #7d6543;
}
.oneColFixCtr #bannerint #callus p {
    color: #7d6543;
}
#warning {
    background-image:url(/images/warning%20bar.png);
    height: 50px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#intwarn {
    margin: 13px;
}

#intwarn p {
    color: #fff
}
#warning #intwarn p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.oneColFixCtr #page #content table {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.oneColFixCtr #page #content #col2 #hp_ftcol2news {
    color: #FFF;
}
.oneColFixCtr #page #content #col2 #hp_ftcol2news p b {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If anyone has suggestions on how I can stop these divs cutting off prematurely (bannerph and ct) I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: Which version of IE? You could try triggering hasLayout with something like `_height: 1%`, `position: relative` or `zoom: 1`.

Comment: have you tried using overflow:hidden; rather than overflow:visible; for ct I'm not sure if IE likes overflow:visible...

Comment: you could also put overflow:hidden on the div with the id of col2

Comment: okay, I've tried both overflow:visible and overflow:hidden , with no luck. The "ct" div appears to cut off at the bottom of the div called "ftcol2foll" ( I checked this by adding text to ftcol2foll to make it bigger, and "ct" expanded to reach the bottom margin of "ftcol2foll". But I don't think this should happen, as all three floating elements (divs "ftcol2off, ftcol2foll and ftcol2news) are all in one div called col2...

Answer (score 0):

The default value for a div overflow is visible so declaring this in the CSS wouldn't have any effect unless you were overriding it from elsewhere.

Try using overflow: hidden; on #ct and #col2 as this should clear the floating column on the right.

Comment: okay, I've tried both overflow:visible and overflow:hidden , with no luck. The "ct" div appears to cut off at the bottom of the div called "ftcol2foll" ( I checked this by adding text to ftcol2foll to make it bigger, and "ct" expanded to reach the bottom margin of "ftcol2foll". But I don't think this should happen, as all three floating elements (divs "ftcol2off, ftcol2foll and ftcol2news) are all in one div called col2...

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know the exact version of the ie browser that is showing this issue. I tested the site in ie 7 and firefox and could not replicate the issue. in ie7 the div is not cut off, but you also do not have opacity on it as well. I would suggest elaborating on the details a little bit, because it could be a number of compatibility issues you are having. All the comments and answers so far have been guesses since we do not have all the information needed to determine the root cause.

Comment: It was IE9 I tested it on to get this issue. The opacity was made by a small png tile as the background (repeat)